# ActionController::MethodNotAllowed (Only get and post requests are allowed.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action

Not sure what's going on. I've used the following bit of code to try and edit the name of a category, but I'm getting the error message above. My code for the form and submit for the edit is: -

```
<% form_for :category, :url => categories_url(@category),:html => { :method => :put } do |f| -%>
<p>Name: <br /><%= f.text_field :name, :size => 60 %></p>
<%= submit_tag 'Save' %> or <%= link_to 'cancel', admin_categories_url%>
```

So pretty straight forward stuff. My controller code is: -
  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

# PUT /categories/1
  # PUT /categories/1.xml
  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.update_attributes(params[:category])

```
respond_to do |wants|
  wants.html { redirect_to admin_categories_url }
  wants.xml  { render :xml => @category.to_xm }
end
```

end

This code has worked for other things - such as blog articles, so I'm not sure where I{"m going wrong. Help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `:url => category_url(@category)` (non-plural).

Answer (score 2):

This tends to be a bit cleaner... Let the Routing system figure out how best to save the @category.

**/app/controllers/admin_categories_controller.rb** (guessed at this)

```
def new
  @category = Category.new
end
```

**/app/views/admin_categories/new.html.erb**

```
<% form_for @category do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :name%>: <%= f.text_field :name, :size=>60%>
</p>
<%= f.submit :save%> or <%= link_to 'cancel', admin_categories_url%>
```